# taskgated erorrs in syslog for macports installed software

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

Whenever I run things that I've installed via macports (like tree, wget, etc) I get the following log message (I'm dumping *.* into this particular log, so it may be fairly low priority).

```
/usr/libexec/taskgated[pid]: no system signature for unsigned /opt/local/bin/tree (or wget, etc)
```

Any idea what this is and how to squash it?

running 10.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from the new authentication policy Apple introduced in Leopard.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/taskgated.8.html

I just filter it out in my syslog using syslog-ng.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled taskgated.

```
# launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
```

Comment: What side-effects might this have? Isn't taskgated necessary for the stability of the programs?

Comment: The side effect is disabling 3rd party's application code sign check, the alert window is showed in the first launch after downloading application from web site.